# Cannot format log messages in play framework scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I cannot get log messages formatted correctly in play 2.2.1 scala.

I am using the standard application-logger.xml file in the conf directory, as described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/SettingsLogger
I also have commented out all logging specific settings in application.conf.

Yet, when trying to log something with this code from within one of my controllers:

```
import play.api.Logger
...
play.api.Logger.info("hello")
```

my logs in logs/application.log look like this:

```
2014-01-09 19:06:25,536 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 
hello
```

So, apparently the formatting is ignored for my "hello" log entry.

I would have expected somthing like this:

```
2014-01-09 19:06:25,536 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 
2014-01-09 19:06:25,536 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5 hello
```

What am i missing?

Comment: put the "logger.Play=INFO" back into the conf

Comment: tried it, that did not change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the sample configuration from the documentation then it seems to me that it's outputting exactly what the pattern specifies.

```
%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n
```

---

The first bit:

> **`%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread`**
>   `> 2014-01-09 19:06:25,536 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5`

Followed by a new line:

> **`%n`**

Followed by the message, exception, and another new line:

> **`%message%n%xException%n`**
>   `> hello`
>   `>`

---

To get what you're expecting you would need to repeat that first bit of the pattern between the first `%n` and `%message`.

```
%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %message%n%xException%n
```

Comment: That was it. I was not aware that both lines stemmed from the single command. I did not recognize the %n character.